# jQuery CSS font-family not working with quotes

Tags: jquery, css, font-face, font-family

I'm using 2 font-faces and wish to switch between them using jQuery, thing is my font-face's name is 'ArvoBold' and when I use:

```
css('font-family','ArvoBold')
```

it changes to a non-existing font named ArvoBold (no-quotes)! I've tried to make it work with:

```
css("font-family","'ArvoBold'")
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried to create a variable:

```
var fontvar="'"+"ArvoBold"+"'";
css('font-family',fontvar);
```

And also with no success, because on the CSS of the element (checked using 
Google Chrome's inspector) it keeps using ArvoBold instead of 'ArvoBold'.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance!

John

Comment: Why does your font have quotes in its name?

Comment: *How* does your font have quotes in its name?

Comment: why don't you change font's name? because all of our answers not working. i don't think it is possible too.

Comment: I endend up using another solution going with a change of class to change the font. I still don't know why it's happening. Arvobold is a font-face available from font-squirrel and I still don't understand why I had that problem with the quotes but who cares now! It's solved lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of your exact implementation, but this works by escaping the single quotes in the string:

```
$(".font-face").css("font-family","\'ArvoBold\'");
```

Why do you need the single quotes?

Quick Test on escaping the single quotes outputs 'ArvoBold' in the content div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<style>
#content{border:solid 1px red;width:100px;height:100px;text-align:center;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#content").html("\'ArvoBold\'");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He doesn't want to change his font to `ArvoBold`, but to `'ArvoBold'`.

Comment: That's why I asked him about the need for single quotes

Comment: After testing and debugging I found your answer to work indeed. So thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define selector and correct your [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) brackets.

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcwkx/10/)

```
var fontvar = 'ArvoBold';
$('.mySelector').css({'font-family':fontvar});​
```

Note: Don't forgot to use [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) too.

Comment: Now try it with `'ArvoBold'` instead of `Arial` and see if it still works.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can write

```
font-family: Arial;
```

as well as

```
font-family: 'Arial';
```

and it has the same meaning. It is therefore to be expected that in

```
'ArvoBold'
```

the quotes are interpreted as string delimiters and not as a part of the string.

You could try escaping the quotes, i.e.

```
font-family: "\'ArvoBold\'"
```

although, I must repeat BoltClock's question: Why do you have quotes in a font name?

Comment: he should change his font's name, your solution does not work either: http://jsfiddle.net/Mcwkx/12/

Comment: @barlasapaydin Well, yes, that's probably the easiest solution (if not the only one).

Comment: I know it should work but somehow it didn't lol escaping the quotes does indeed work. The quotes are common in all of font-squirrel font-face names so I just end up using them anyway.