# How to Change Font-family using JQuery's .css() function?

Tags: jquery, css, font-family

I have already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654708/jquery-changing-font-family-and-font-size) and I used what was given there to the best of my ability, but it really doesn't help.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903492/jquery-css-font-family-not-working-with-quotes), but it didn't help either.

Here is my JQuery (not finished with cases, but the case I have is the one I need it for):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sub").click(function(){
    var initial = $('#name').val().substr(0, 1);
    var name = $('#name').val();
        switch(initial) {
            case "K":
            $("body").css("background-image", "url(background2.png)");
            $("div").css("background-color", "#eee5e5");
            $(".img").css("display", "none");
            $(".me").css("padding-top", "100px");
            $(".me").css("padding-bottom", "100px");
            $(".me").css("color", "#570000");
            $("p").css("font-family", "rebel");
            $("a").css("font-family", "rebel");
            $("#h1").css("font-family", "highway");
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

My #h1 in CSS (my p and a tags don't have css already):

```
#h1{
    background-color:#ef6d3a;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
    border-width:3px;
    font-family:hobo;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width:1224px;
    right: 10;
}
```

And my imported fonts:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:peignot;
    src:url(peignot.ttf);
}
    @font-face{
    font-family:binner;
    src:url(ufonts.com_binner.ttf);
}
    @font-face{
    font-family:rebel;
    src:url(rb.ttf);
}
@font-face{
    font-family:highway;
    src:url(hth.ttf);
}
@font-face{
    font-family:hobo;
    src:url(ufonts.com_hobo.ttf);
}
```

Whenever I run the function, everything but the font changes. What am I doing wrong, and what do I need to do?

Comment: Aren't styles usually camelCased when used in jQuery?  e.g. fontFamily?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery css font-family not working with quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903492/jquery-css-font-family-not-working-with-quotes)

Comment: Nevermind.  That doesn't seem to matter.  Did your TTF files resolve properly?

Comment: if you know what all those styles will be, it will be simpler and look a lot cleaner to toggle classes instead of inline style ... much simpler to undo

Comment: @Kris Oye Yes they did, they work when used in CSS also

Comment: @charlitfl I'm doing this for a class, and I'm at a level were that would most likely not be accepted

Comment: don't know why it wouldn't be accepted, it's the most common approach

Comment: The camel casing doesn't matter that way, only when using the name identifier as multi-property object to define lots of css at once. @Kris

Comment: It has to do with using the custom fonts. I do this all the time, and use the same code calls. I do not do it with the UTF fonts like that though, only regualr fonts. Like office to monospace, etc.

Comment: @charlietfl my teacher is very picky, sadly about going much out of her teaching range

Comment: Url's on fonts are not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted your stuff into a pastebin and modified it so it changes the font using **built-in fonts** and it worked ok. Link: http://jsbin.com/xijejelala/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Leads me to believe your font files aren't resolving properly as per Kris Oye's comment. Use F12 developer tools and go to the network tab and refresh, and check to see that your files aren't 404ing on attempted load.

Now, a potentially easier way to handle this would be to do this with the CSS:

```
body.initial-k #h1 { /* styles for #h1 */ }
body.initial-k p { ... }
body.initial-d #h1 {}
body.initial-d p {}
```

Then use `$("body").removeClass("initial-k").addClass("initial-d")` to swap things around.

Comment: I had saved my fonts as rb.ttf.ttf and hth.ttf.ttf by accident, thank you! Sorry for the trouble